# SQL Server equivalent of MySQL DATE_FORMAT()

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Hope we're having a good day and all set for Christmas.

Got a quick question.  I'm converting a MySQL function into SQL Server, I've got most of the function converted except for one part which has the following:

```
@description = CONCAT(@description, date_format(@INLastUpdated, '%H:%i %d %b %Y'))
```

What I'm trying to do is to basically recreate the [date_format function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to format the date in the same way specified, but I'm not sure how to do it.  from what I've seen in the MySQL documentation the format selected would give hour:minute day / short month name / year.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Here's an idea: Format dates in the display, not the database!

Comment: I would love to do that, but the company aren't willing to change the app that connects to the database, they want the functionality to the same.  So the formatting has to be done database side.

Comment: Cast and convert do the job in SQL server

Comment: Although you've accepted an answer, it would have been helpful if you had mentioned your SQL Server version: SQL Server 2012 has the [FORMAT() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) which would do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @description VARCHAR(1000) = 'test'
DECLARE @INLastUpdated DATETIME = '2012-12-21 14:32:22'
SET @description = @description + ' ' 
    + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @INLastUpdated, 8), 5) + ' ' 
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @INLastUpdated, 106)

SELECT @description
```

But be careful as format 106 depends on local language settings. Read more on **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent function is [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187928.aspx). But you're basically out of luck. SQL Server does not allow to cherry-pick the date tokens. You need to browse the available full date built-in formats and choose one, or try to compose an output by string concatenation, as in:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 103) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 114)
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SQL Server? In SQL Server 2012 we now have the FORMAT function.

This, in MySQL

```
date_format(@INLastUpdated, '%H:%i %d %b %Y')
```

translates into something like this for SQL Server 2012 using the FORMAT function:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = GETDATE();
SELECT  FORMAT(@d, 'HH:mm d MMM yyyy', 'en-US') AS 'DateTime Result';
```

[BOL SQL Server 2012 > FORMAT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)